# How to set default stack in IntelliJ Idea cloudbees plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, cloudbees

I have jsf webapp. I have successfully deployed it to Cloudbees using steps from http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/12/deploy-web-apps-to-cloudbees-from-intellij-idea-12/.

The problem is that the app won't work until I change the ClickStack to web application profile. The default one is Tomcat. My change is always lost each time I deploy/update the app from IntelliJ Idea. Deploying the app from PaaS console works without problem.

Is there any setting to make the Idea plugin remember the used stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a bug, [reported in YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-100205), star/vote the issue to receive notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around. Include a jsf implementation to the app.

Answer (score 0):

Support for ClickStacks had been added to IDEA CB integration, staring from next IDEA 13 EAP, it will be possible to choose between "Basic Java Webapp (Tomcat)" and "Java EE 6 Web Profile (JBoss)" options.